# Auto close navbar after click on link responsive mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
I add also my CSS code of navbar, all is working well, only I need is auto close when click on link 
/* navbar */

nav{
  height: 4rem;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #efefef;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;

}



/*Styling logo*/
/* .logo{
  padding:1vh 1vw;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo img {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
} */


/*Styling Links*/
.nav-list{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none; 
  width: 80vw;
  padding: 0 0.7vw;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-list li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 1em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.nav-list li a:hover {
  color: #1abc9c;
}
.nav-list li {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
}
.nav-list li a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  margin: 0 0 0 10%;
}
.nav-list li a:hover::before{
  width: 80%;
}




/*Styling Hamburger Icon*/
.hamburger div{
  width: 30px;
  height:3px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.hamburger{
  display: none;
}

/*Stying for small screens*/
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  nav{
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 3;

  }
  .hamburger{
      display:block;
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      right: 5%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
      z-index: 2;
      transition: all 0.7s ease;
  }
  .nav-list {
      position: fixed;
      background: #efefef;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      flex-direction: column;
      clip-path: circle(50px at 90% -20%);
      -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at 90% -10%);
      transition: all 1s ease-out;
      pointer-events: none;
     
  }

  
  .nav-list.open{
      clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
      -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
      pointer-events: all;

  }

  .nav-list li{
      opacity: 0;
      margin-top: 3em;
  }
  .nav-list li:nth-child(1){
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  }
  .nav-list li:nth-child(2){
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
  }
  .nav-list li:nth-child(3){
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
  }
  .nav-list li:nth-child(4){
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.7s;
  }
  .nav-list li:nth-child(5){
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.8s;
  }
  .nav-list li:nth-child(6){
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.9s;
      margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-list li:nth-child(7){
      transition: all 0.5s ease 1s;
      margin: 0;
  }
  li.fejd{
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
/*Animating Hamburger Icon on Click*/
.toggle .line1{
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}
.toggle .line2{
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
  width:0;
}
.toggle .line3{
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}


/* /navbar end */
```

I would like to close navbar when a user clicks on link in responsive mode. I have tried a few examples but it doesn't work for me. Thank you very much!

```
<nav class="navBar" id="navbar">
      <div class="hamburger">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
     </div>`
 


      <ul class="nav-list" id="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#parents" class="nav-item">Parents</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-section" class="nav-item">A propos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-item">Temoignagez</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my js code. All is working well! I only need to close nav when an user clicks on links
// navbar

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-list");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-list li");

hamburger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
   //Animate Links
    navLinks.classList.toggle("open");
    links.forEach(link => {
        link.classList.toggle("fejd");
        
    });

    //Hamburger Animation
    hamburger.classList.toggle("toggle");
});

const navToggle = document.getElementById('nav-toggle');
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.navLink').parentElement;

navToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-open');
    
});


 </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by close the navbar, do you mean hiding it?

Comment: hiding it yes, when a user clicks on link because my nav take a whole screen in responsive mode when one clicks on hamburger btn

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: I just added my JS code!

Comment: can you also add your css code?

Comment: I just added it

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach to apply addeventlistener to all elements

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item').forEach(link=>{
  link.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert();
  })
})
```